# replace comment from css file on golang

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

1.Данные из файла my.css записываю в переменную c01 так:

```
    c01, err := ioutil.ReadFile("C:/comp/my.css")
       if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

3.Получается отправить на клиента в браузер так:

```
    w.Write([]byte(c01))
```

2.Хочу до отправки убрать все комменты типа /* ... */.
Делаю *до отправки* на клиента так:

```
ccmt := regexp.MustCompile(`/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/`)
но так не получается: ccmt.ReplaceAll([]byte(c01), []byte(""))
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно.

Comment: Не стоит искать блоки текста такой регуляркой, задачу проще(а главное менее ресурсоемко) можно решить в лоб перебором, по одному символу

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, похоже Вы правы. В приведенном случае с регуляркой я понял, что она работает, но оставляет лишние пробелы или пустые строки, - если комментов группа. Через TrimSpace получилось убрать пробелы, но остались *пустые* строки на месте где отрабатывал regexp. В общем пока так и не победил. Не поделитесь рабочим кодом перебора для моего решения под css комменты?

Comment: Может, `[ \t]*/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/[ \t\r]*\n?` подойдёт?